# Modify app.config during installation

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, windows-installer, installshield

How do I modify app.config during installation? I need to have the installer prompt for user input which is captured during installation. This input needs to be saved in app.config as it is used when the installed program runs. Please help me understand how to make the installer prompt for input and modify app.config. I am using Visual Studio 2012 and InstallShield LE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. I simply wrote a 2nd program that gets run immediately after installation of the main app. This 2nd program makes the modification and saves the config file. Works like a charm.